# Where can I check whether a particular jdk version is compatible with Windows server

Tags: java, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

Where can I check whether a particular jdk version is compatible with Windows server 2008 and/or server 2012.

I need below list.But I didn't found in oracle website.

```
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 11
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 12
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 15
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 18
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 21
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 22
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 6
J2SE Development Kit 5.0 Update 7
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 10
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 11
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 12
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 15
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 16
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 18
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 19
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 2
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 21
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 22
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 4
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 5
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 6
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 7
J2SE Runtime Environment 5.0 Update 9
```

Comment: It worth remembering that not only is Java 5.0 not supported publicly, neither is Java 6, or Java 7.  This means that while they might have worked with the version of the Windows available at the time, they might not work with more recent updates.

Answer (score 1):

Those versions of Java are all ancient history.  You can find them in the archive section the Java Oracle download site:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html

According to the Wikipedia page on [Java version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history):

> *"... Windows Vista is the newest version of Windows that J2SE 5 was supported on prior to Java 5 going end of life in October 2009."*.

I also found the platform support page in the Java 5 documentation:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/system-configurations-139801.html

which lists the editions of Server 2008 that are supported.

But frankly, you should be trying to move away from Java 5 as fast as you can.

Comment: Here we have option to download but there are no details of compatibility here.